# When I press enter inside an inputfield my React form still submits even though I have set preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, forms

Very basic form

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
event.preventDefault()
}
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
....
</form>
```

When I press enter inside one of the input fields however it still submits. Although the default behaviour is not being trigged (reloading the page) it is still executing the handleSubmit function.

Comment: Pretty sure it's because you're using an async function, you can't do that as it will *immediately* return before your code runs and the page will reload before you call `.preventDefault`. Any place you see `async` in Javascript code you need to think "this will run later at some unknown point in the future". So anything that needs to happen *now* (like stopping a form from submitting) needs to not be async.

Comment: @JaredSmith I thought so too before posting but I rewrote it to a sync function with an anonymous async function inside that started after the `.preventDefault` call. So not sure what is going on now.

Comment: @JaredSmith also this would mean you would never be able to preventDefault in any form when making a post request without using async or promises.

Comment: On the contrary, consider: `const submitHandler = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); const someFunctionThatUsesAwaitAndDoesAllTheWork = async () => {...}; someFunctionThatUsesAwaitAndDoesAllTheWork(); };`

Comment: can you please share the full code that doesn't work?
everything working just fine when i tried it.